# Number of ways to choose bagels

Tags: combinatorics

A bagel store sells six different kinds of bagels. Suppose you choose 15 bagels at random. What is the probability that your choice contains at least one bagel of each kind? If one of the bagels is Sesame, what is the probability that your choice contains at least three Sesame bagels?

My approach to the first problem was the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=15, x_i \geq 1$ which is the same as $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=9, y_i \geq 0$ which has $ 14 \choose 9$ solutions. So that is 2002 solutions.  And there are in total $22 \choose 15$ solutions to the equation without the restriction. So in a percentage, there is a $\frac{2002}{15504}$ or 12.9% we will get one of each kind.

For the second problem, I used the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=15, x_1 \geq 3, x_i \geq 0, i \neq 1$.  This gives $17 \choose 12$ solutions, which gives a $\frac{6188}{15504}$ or a 39% chance of getting a sesame bagel.

Is my approach for both of these right? (The percentages of these happening seem really high)

Answer (score 1):

A Markovian matrices solution. I like this formalism because it gives more controls on the algorithm and leads to less faulty solutions in general.

To get one of each kind, we define $7$ states, from $0$ to $6$, related to the number of colors found. $k$ is the size of the sample, $k=15$ and $n$ the number of states. We start with $0$ colors. The 1st "throw" gives always a transition to the 1st color. At the next steps , the state stays unchanged or changes with the couple of probabilities $(\frac{s}{n} , \frac{n-s}{n})$. When it comes to $6$, it stays unchanged.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end {pmatrix} \times {\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & {\frac{1}{n}} & {\frac{n-1}{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & {\frac{2}{n}} & {\frac{n-2}{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & {\frac{3}{n}} & {\frac{n-3}{n}} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\frac{4}{n}} & {\frac{n-4}{n}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\frac{5}{n}} & {\frac{n-5}{n}} \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \end {pmatrix}}^{k} =$
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end {pmatrix} \times {\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & {\frac{1}{6}} & {\frac{5}{6}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & {\frac{2}{6}} & {\frac{4}{6}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & {\frac{3}{6}} & {\frac{3}{6}} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\frac{4}{6}} & {\frac{2}{6}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\frac{5}{6}} & {\frac{1}{6}} \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \end {pmatrix}}^{15} = $

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{78364164096} & \frac{27305}{26121388032} & \frac{11875505}{19591041024} & \frac{35296625}{1088391168} & \frac{43909775}{136048896} & \frac{233718485}{362797056} \end{pmatrix} =$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0. & 1.27609×10^{-11} & 1.04531×10^{-6} & 0.00060617 & 0.0324301 & 0.32275 & \color{blue}{0.644213}  \end{pmatrix}$

[computed here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B1,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D.%7B%7B0,1,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1%2F6,5%2F6,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,2%2F6,4%2F6,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,3%2F6,3%2F6,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,4%2F6,2%2F6,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,5%2F6,1%2F6%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,1%7D%7D%5E15)

Similarly to get 3 Sesames, we must build another matrix with 4 states, 0, 1 , 2 or at least 3 sesames. Now the probability of transition is always $\frac16$ and then the probability to stay is the complement to 1. We start with 0 Sesame.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end {pmatrix} \times {\begin{pmatrix} {\frac{n-1}{n}} & {\frac{1}{n}} & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & {\frac{n-1}{n}} & {\frac{1}{n}} & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & {\frac{n-1}{n}} & {\frac{1}{n}}  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \end {pmatrix}}^{k} =  $
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end {pmatrix} \times {\begin{pmatrix} {\frac{5}{6}} & {\frac{1}{6}} & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & {\frac{5}{6}} & {\frac{1}{6}} & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & {\frac{5}{6}} & {\frac{1}{6}}  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \end {pmatrix}}^{15} = $
$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{30517578125}{470184984576} & \frac{30517578125}{156728328192} & \frac{42724609375}{156728328192} & \frac{219940843951}{470184984576} \end{pmatrix} = $
$\begin{pmatrix}0.0649055 & 0.194716 & 0.272603 & \color{blue}{0.467775} \end{pmatrix}$

[computed here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B1,+0,+0,+0%7D+.+%7B%7B5%2F6,1%2F6,0,0%7D,%7B0,5%2F6,1%2F6,0%7D,%7B0,0,5%2F6,1%2F6%7D,%7B0,0,0,1%7D%7D%5E15)

Answer (score 0):

The first probability is given by
$$ \frac{{15 \brace 6}\cdot 6!}{6^{15}}\approx \color{red}{64,\!42\%} $$
since a working choice is associated with a bijective function from $[1,15]$ to $[1,6]$. ${15\brace 6}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), that can be computed through the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The second probability is given by
$$ \frac{1}{6^{15}}\sum_{k=3}^{15}\binom{15}{k}5^{15-k}\approx \color{red}{46,\!78\%}$$
since a working choice is associated with a function $f$ from $[1,15]$ to $[1,6]$ with the property that $\left|f^{-1}(1)\right|\geq 3$.

Comment: Isn't $6^{15}$ counting the same box of bagels multiple times because the box containing 1 plain then 2  everything bagels is the same as 2 everything then 1 plain.  My point is that the order doesn't matter when choosing bagels, I believe. So I'm not sure if your answer is correct.

Comment: @AndroidFish: I am not sure I understand your actual question. $6^{15}$ is obviously the number of strings with $15$ characters over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{S,T,U,X,Y,Z\}$ where $S$ stands for *S*esame.

Comment: Yes, strings would be unique.  But if you are buying a box of bagels, then the order doesn't matter anymore. So $6^{15}$ in the first part and the second is counting the same box multiple times because there are many orderings of a box of bagels, but it is still the same box.  Does that make sense, or am I going crazy? Thats why I went with $22 \choose 15$ because it disregards order.

Comment: @AndroidFish: but obviously a fixed string represting an outcome and a permutated string have the same probability to occur and contain the same number of $S$-characters/bagels.

Comment: I assume you meant to say a *surjective* function from $[1, 15]$ to $[1, 6]$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are both correct, you just have one tiny little error which I'm guessing is a typo. You said the total number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 15, x_i \geq 0$ is ${22 \choose 5}$ . But if we solve for the number of integral solutions of the above equation, we get ${15 + 6 - 1 \choose 15} = {20 \choose 15} = 15504$ .

Other than that, your answers are correct.